# Behavior of the function with the follwing properties

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

We know that a function with period $a$ satisfies $f(x+a)=f(x)$ for each $x$ in its domain. What can you conclude about a function which has a derivative everywhere and satisfies an equation of the form
$$f(x+a)=bf(x),$$
for all $x$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants?

I am stuck with this problem. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Put $g(x)=\exp(-x\log(b)/a)f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x+2a) = bf(x+a) = b^2 f(x),  f(x+na) = b^n f(x)$  looks like $f(x)$ is the product of an exponential function and a periodic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start by some basic examples to have an idea, e.g. take $a=1$ and start with $f(x) = 1 \forall x \in (0,1]$ and see what happens over $(1,2]$ and $(2,3]$ to get some idea.

Basically if $b=1$, each consecutive period is a copy of the preceding one. If $b>1$, you will scale them up, and $b<1$ will scale them down.